# Creation of a Structure of Cells - MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, structure

I have a set of data as can be seen from the attached snapshot. As can be observed, it is a set of repetitive data. I am trying to write a code such that the code would create a main structure "RoadXML" with all the subsequent text in the cell as structure elements.

For eg: " RoadXML.Network.SubNetworks.SubNetwork.RoadNetwork.Grounds.Ground" should produce a structure RoadXML which has a struct element "Networks" which inturn is a structure. Likewise " Networks" should have " Subnetworks" as an element which is a structure and so on... Furthurmore, the rest of the data should append itself to the main structure under its respective fields. Hence in the end only one structure would remain with all the data in the excel sheet as its structure elements.

Now the problem is that, when repetitive sets of elements are present in the excel sheet as can be seen from the screenshot, only the last set of data remains thus overwriting the data that has been already stored. That is to say (with reference to the attached screenshot) data from rows 30 to 34 over writes all the data from rows 15 to 29 that has been alreaady stored.

**UPDATE**

To be a bit more clear about my problem, during the iteration from row 15 to 19, my code stores the data from the first column as structures in the exact format as shown in the snap. i.e. *RoadXML* is a structure which has *Network* which in turn is a structure which has *SubNetworks* which inturn is a structure which has *SubNetwork* and so on till the last parameter. In the end, we'll have *Ground* as a structure inside *Grounds*.

Since A15 and A20 are the same data, once row 20 is encountered the code should convert *Ground* which was earlier a structure into a cell, create a 1x1 structure in the cell which has ''Attributes''(structure) in it as a field. Once ''Attribute'' has been created, ''granulosity'', ''grip''; ''name'' and ''type'' should be appended into ''Attributes'' with their corresponding values from column B.

[image]
 [image]

Comment: Please state what you want the code to do in such case instead of overwrite. Otherwise, the problem isn't clear

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. The code should create a cell array with each set of data. For example, one set of data (wrt the screenshot) is from row 15 to 19. So that would mean there are 4 sets of data now. So instead of overwriting the data, i require the code to create a 1x4 cell array. i shall edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every new line in the excel file:

1. Check if part of the new field path already exists.
   For example, after line 2 "RoadXML.Network.SubNetworks.SubNetwork.RoadNetwork.Grounds.Ground.Attributes.granulosity" is created.
   On line 3, the path till "Attributes" already exists. Only the field "grip" is missing.

Read [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95923-is-there-a-matlab-function-that-can-check-if-a-field-exists-in-a-matlab-structure) about checking if a certain field exists in a nested structure.

2. If part of path exists, start add fields where the existing path ends.
3. If the full path, including the last field exists, choose what you want it to do. Overwrite? Make that field a vetor?

Example run:

Line 15: Ground doesn't exists, so created:
`RoadXML....Ground{1,1}.Text=""`
Lines 16-19: Ground exists, add the attributes
`RoadXML....Ground{1,1}.Attributes.X=Y`
Line 20: Ground contains 1 cell, so add a new one:
`RoadXML....Ground{1,2}.Text=""`

And so on..

Comment: Are you having trouble checking if the field already exists, or in adding the new value?

Comment: hi RadioJava,
I am already using "isfield" to check whether fields exists in the structure. like i have updated in the question, it is necessary that the repeated set of data are converted into structures and these structures should be stored as elements of a cell array.

To be more clear, from the screenshot, the output should be one 1x4 cell array "Ground". Each element of this cell array would be a structure ("Attributes"). In turn "Attributes" should also be a structure which has granulosity, grip, name and type as structure members.

Comment: Wouldn't "Ground" be a 1x1, containing a struct "Attributes" which is a 1x4 cell array containing fields {"granulosity","grid","name","type"}?

Comment: If we take one set of data (for eg row 15 to 19), yes "ground" would be a 1x1. But the goal is to have all the data from row 15 to 34 in this format. row 15 to 19 is one set of data (making ground 1x1 as you said), row 20 to 24 is the second set of data (making ground 1x2) and so on.

Comment: Does group have a value, other than being a struct? what should be the result of line 1?

Comment: Hi,

Thank you very much for taking time to help me out. I have updated my initial query and added a new snap too for your reference.

Comment: Ok, so for every new repetition of ground you want to set its new values to the current number of occurrence. You can have a counter that counts the number of times the line format as line 15 appeared, and every time just set:
'....Grounds.Ground{1,counter}.Attributes.granulosity=0.5' 
and so on

Comment: You can do it with a counter if its easier, or check every time the size of the Ground if it exists.
I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: Cool... thanks for the tip... really appreciate it :)